# How to export data from a test package and use them in another test package in go

Tags: go

I'm creating some vars in `B_test.go` and I want to use those same vars in `A_test.go`. Can this be done in Go? I think the question boils down to whether I can export functions from `B_test.go` during `go test` only.

Example:

In package `A_test.go`

```
package A

var from_B = B.ExportedVars()
```

In package `B_test.go`

```
package B

ExportedVars() []int {
    return []int{0, 1)
}
```

Running `go test` gives

```
undefined B.ExportedVars
```

Putting `ExportedVars()` in `B.go` instead of `B_test.go` solves the problem but this is not what I want. I want it to live in the test file.

Comment: A file `B_test.go` is **not** part of `package B` (but only of the test executable for package B).  If you want to export something from a package you'll have to put it *in* the package (eg. file `B.go`). Sidenote: There is no notion of "export **to** some specific package": Stuff is exported to everyone or not exported.

Comment: Thanks Volker. I suppose what I'm trying to do is similar to https://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/net/http/export_test.go. I understand that `B_test.go` is not part of `package B` but I though that during testing the exported functions of `B_test.go` are built and available to use in other test packages. Sidenote: I will edit the question to clarify.

Comment: @mns, what is it that export_test.go does that you're trying to do? Nothing from that file is used outside of the http package.

Comment: @JimB the functions exported by `export_test.go` are used in the `http_test` package, which is technically a different package than `http`. Isn't it? For example check the `NewLoggingConn` which is defined in `export_test.go` just to export the `newLoggingConn` of the `http` package. Then this is used in https://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/net/http/transport_test.go. Am I missing something?

Comment: @mns, yes they are different packages. I don't recall the exact rules, but you can have a _test package that is in a separate package to test your package from outside its namespace, but your package is still built under test (and hence export_test.go is compiled into http). This still can't expose anything from _test.go files to other packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Packages cannot see exported symbols from other package's test files, because the `go` tools do not build those files into the installed package. One option you do have is to use [build constraints](http://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Build_Constraints).

Create a file or files that contain everything you want to export for whatever reason, without using the `_test.go` suffix. Then mark them for build only when using your chosen tag.

```
// +build export
package normal

var ExportedName = somethingInternal
```

When testing a package dependent on this `ExportedName` in package `normal`, you will need to add the `-tags export` flag to the test run.

This is also useful for various other reasons, like having a `-tags debug` build, which can add extra functionality such as importing [`net/http/pprof`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/pprof/) or [`expvar`](http://golang.org/pkg/expvar/)